# How to call similar variables in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to get set if statement of no. of count of array from database. I already have a if statement checking the count but I am unable to use it in my file.

Help me replicate the count if statement here. I want to wrap pro_type and is_pro in if statement of no. of counts similar in reaferandearn page .

**My function where I need if count statement :**

users.php file

```
public function update_valid_refer_point($id){

    global $db; 
    
    $user_balance = $db->where('id',$id)
                        ->getOne('users',array('balance'));
    $_POST['pro_type'] =4;
    $_POST['is_pro'] =1;
    $bal =$user_balance['balance']+500;
   
    $updated = $db->where('id', $id)
                    ->update('users', array('pro_type' => 4,'is_pro' => 1,'balance' => $bal));
    return TRUE;
}
```

**The file where I have similar if count statement but I have no idea how to use it above :**

referandearn.php

```
if(count($data['refferal_data']['data']) > 0){
    
<?php
    }>
```

referandearn controller :

```
Class Referearn extends Theme { 
    public static function LoadreffralUsers() {
        global $_AJAX, $_CONTROLLERS;
        $data            = '';
        $ajax_class      = realpath($_CONTROLLERS . 'aj.php');
        $ajax_class_file = realpath($_AJAX . 'loadmore.php');
        if (file_exists($ajax_class_file)) {
            require_once $ajax_class;
            require_once $ajax_class_file;
            $_POST['page'] = 1;
            $loadmore      = new Loadmore();
            $refferal_users   = $loadmore->refferal_users();
            parent::$data['refferal_data'] = $refferal_users;
            /*if (isset($refferal_users['html'])) {
                $data = $refferal_users['html'];
            }*/
            
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

And loadmore referusers function :

```
 function refferal_users() {
        global $db, $_BASEPATH, $_DS,$_excludes;
        if (self::ActiveUser() == NULL) {
            return array(
                'status' => 403,
                'message' => __('Forbidden')
            );
        }
        $error     = '';
        $page      = 0;
        $perpage   = 7;
        $html      = '';
        $html_imgs = '';
        $template  = '';
        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
            if (isset($_POST[ 'page' ]) && (!is_numeric($_POST[ 'page' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'page' ]))) {
                $error = '<p>• ' . __('no page number found.') . '</p>';
            } else {
                $page = (int) Secure($_POST[ 'page' ]) - 1;
            }
        }
        if ($error == '') {
            $limit  = $perpage;
            $offset = $page * $perpage;
            //$query  = GetRefferalUserQuery(self::ActiveUser()->id, $limit, $offset);
            //exit;
            //$refferal_users       = $db->rawQuery($query);
            $sql = 'SELECT U.id,U.online,U.lastseen,U.username,U.avater,U.country,U.first_name,U.last_name,U.location,U.birthday,U.language,U.relationship,U.height,U.body,U.smoke,U.ethnicity,U.pets,U.gender, RU.refferalDate, RU.refferalCode FROM users U INNER JOIN refferalusers RU ON RU.refferalBy = U.id ';
            $sql .= ' WHERE RU.refferalTo = '.self::ActiveUser()->id.' AND ( ';
            $sql .= ' U.verified = "1" AND U.privacy_show_profile_random_users = "1" ';
            // to exclude blocked users
            $notin = ' AND U.id NOT IN (SELECT block_userid FROM blocks WHERE user_id = '.self::ActiveUser()->id.') ';
            // to exclude liked and disliked users users
            $notin .= ' AND U.id NOT IN (SELECT like_userid FROM likes WHERE ( user_id = '.self::ActiveUser()->id.' OR like_userid = '.self::ActiveUser()->id.' ) ) ';
            $sql .= ' ) ';
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY U.id DESC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$offset.';';
            $random_users        = $db->objectBuilder()->rawQuery($sql);
            
            $theme_path = $_BASEPATH . 'themes' . $_DS . self::Config()->theme . $_DS;
            //$template   = $theme_path . 'partails' . $_DS . 'find-matches' . $_DS . 'random_users.php';
            //$template1  = $theme_path . 'partails' . $_DS . 'find-matches' . $_DS . 'matches_imgs.php';
            if (file_exists($template)) {
                foreach ($random_users as $random_user) {
                    if($random_user->id!=(int)auth()->id){
                        ob_start();
                        require($template);
                        $html .= ob_get_contents();
                        ob_end_clean();
                    }
                }
            }
            return array(
                'status' => 200,
                'page' => $page + 2,
                'html' => $html,
                'data' => $random_users
            );
        } else {
            return array(
                'status' => 400,
                'message' => $error
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question and requirements are unclear. Title says similar variable. What do you mean by it

Comment: @IndraKumarS I want similar if count statement, but I dont know how to use the $data['refferal_data']['data'] variable in other php file.

Comment: @IndraKumarS please suggest a solution if you can

Comment: What do you want to count? Why do you want to count it?

Comment: @endeavour I want to count the amount of  usersid in a colummn which tells refered users. I want to reward user if he refers more than n no. of users

Comment: _I want to count the amount of usersid in a colummn which tells refered users_ . And which sql query is associated with this. What object holds this information? Are you simply asking "How to create an sql query to count column X based on a few where clauses". If so, frame your question properly.

Comment: @endeavour I already have a similar if count statement which counts this data in referandearn.php file, but I am not sure how to use the same variable in my other users.php file.

Comment: Do these two files share the same [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)? I assume not. If you need to use the data in a function you need to fetch the data from somewhere - a query or a different function. Assuming the static function `LoadreffralUsers` provides this data. You can do `$data = Referearn::LoadreffralUsers();`. Once you have `$data` variable with the information you need you are free to count any part if it.

Comment: @endeavour so if count statement will be like         $datanew = Referearn::LoadreffralUsers();  count($datanew::$data['refferal_data']['data']   ? . do I need to set include or require once if the scope is not same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233377/discussion-between-dhruvbhati-and-endeavour).

Comment: You need to `include` or `require` the file where the codes reside for the current page to access it (unless of course you use autoload). `Scope` of a variable would simply mean where can you access it. Read more in the docs links earlier. You will need to do `count($datanew['refferal_data']['data'])` - again  a lot of things have been assumed and is not clear in the question.

Comment: @endeavour https://ibb.co/pLmkf2J please check

Comment: In your `LoadreffralUsers()` function you are setting the parent variable with `parent::$data['refferal_data'] = $refferal_users;` and returning `$data` (which is  an empty string). Is that by design? If not you need to return `parent::$data`

Comment: @endeavour it is by design. I am still not able to get the correct count variable. Is there another way. Help please

Comment: @endeavour Can we directly load data from loadmore like the controller is calling. can you assist me with this?